# Can I route a dishwasher drain hose into drain pipe in crawl space?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

We want to add a dishwasher in a kitchen that had none before.  The only D/W location is several feet away from the garbage disposal and it's very awkward to route the drain hose through all the cabinets.  Instead, we would create a high loop on the side of dishwasher, then route it into the crawlspace to connect to the vented kitchen sink drain pipe (we would use a trap to prevent back flow).  In addition to being simpler to do it would also allow us to shorten the distance between the D/W and disposal from 11' to 7'.  Will this method work properly?

Comment: how high ? it does not like hight (sp) to pump water out

Comment: What would you do for the vent ?

Comment: @Ruskes the high loop is one of two ways to provide an air gap (the other is a traditional air gap on top of the counter). One of those is required by code and dishwashers are designed to pump accordingly.

Comment: The loop would go to just underneath the countertop then back down through a hole in the floor to go underneath crawlspace.

Comment: The D/W hose drains into the same pipe as the vented sink drain.  The hose would enter the drain pipe about 2' downstream from the sink.

Comment: where's the trap, where's the vent, where does the hose end?

Comment: The D/W trap is separate from the sink trap and is right under the floor underneath the D/W.  The vent utilizes the same vent as the sink.  The hose ends where it drains into the D/W trap and from there it drains into the drain pipe, which is the drain pipe utilized by the sink.

Comment: newer done something like that, but due to the distance, I would consider using larger pvc pipe that is also tilted

Comment: There will be a 1 1/2" pipe coming from sink and a 1 1/2" pipe coming from D/W.  They meet at a tee, and then turn into a 2" pipe downstream.

Comment: SOUNDS GOOD ......

Comment: Don’t abandon the empty space at the bottom of the cabinet just yet. Great place to run a pipe. The nice part is your can make holes as needed and then hide everything by adding a new toe kick across the span of the cabinets.

Comment: would be helpful to see a diagram of the proposal, with heights, run lengths, slopes, diameters, traps, whys, vents etc...

Comment: We've decided to run the hose into the crawlspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this scenario if there is no room to hook up drain above the floor it is acceptable and legal to have your drain installed into the crawl space as long there is a permanent access panel or door leading to the drain location.

Comment: This answers our question, and we have all that is necessary to meet the requirements.